# How do you remove an app request on the iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

When making app requests on Facebook using the iOS SDK, the developers guide requires that developers clear the request when the app is opened.

> Deleting Requests
>
> When a user is directed to your app by clicking accepting a Request
>   you must delete the request after it has been accepted. Requests are
>   not automatically deleted once they have been clicked, thus it is the
>   developer’s responsibility to clear them once they have been accepted.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting

Is there a function to clear all notifications, or other helpers like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following API will clear a specific app-request:

```
FBRequest *request = [facebookObject requestWithGraphPath:@"REQUEST-ID_USER-ID"
                                    andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
                                    andHttpMethod:@"DELETE"
                                    andDelegate:self];
```

Substitute the request ID for REQUEST-ID and the Facebook user's Id for USER-ID (the underline between the two is important). Change the `andDelegate` and `andParams` as needed, but don't pass a `nil` object to `andParams` otherwise it will completely fail.

To delete all the requests, you need to iterate through all the requests passed in the url in :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

which is probabaly implemented in your app delegate.

All of the user's existing request-ids are comma-separated in the `request_ids` parameter of the `target_url` paramater in the `url` NSURL. This only happens when a user clicks on an app-request notification in the iOS Facebook app and your facebook app has `iOS Native Deep Linking` enabled.

Comment: In my case, target_url is missing the request_ids parameter. My target url is in the format: http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/<APP_ID>. Any ideas why the url might be missing the request_ids parameter?

Comment: lets say I want to delete the request once the user clicks on the request in the notification, then where is the best place to put the code?